# Adding and deleting items in custom model for QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

How better to realize adding and deleting items in a custom model for QTableView, which are working via MVC?

1. By adding custom functions to model: add() and delete(...)?
2. Just implement function update() and add directly elements in list attached with this QTableView.

Comment: You need to implement `QAbstractItemModel::insertRow()` and `QAbstractItemModel::deleteRow()` functions of your model.

Comment: I know this method (I have pointed him in my list). But I have question: it's right way (Qt-style way)?

Comment: If Qt provides such API - it is the right way to do things with this framework.

Comment: But, when we are using QSqlTableModel, we just adding some data to database and then update model by select().

Comment: If you take a look into the QSqlTableModel sources, you will probably find these two functions already implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it depends on the nature of your model:

If your model is holding the data to be shown itself, providing custom methods like `add(const Data &data)` and `remove()` is a common solution - just be sure to call `beginInsertRows`/`endInsertRows` and `beginRemoveRows`/`endRemoveRows` inside those methods.

If you directly access the data storage (List/Map/Whatever), it should be sufficient to just call `insertRow`/`removeRow` after adding new data.